# When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id“, ”splitOn with Multiple relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, orm, dapper

I get the following exception when i try to execute this method :

> When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if
>   you have keys other than Id“

---

```
public static IEnumerable<FinancePositionList> GetFinancialListsForConsecutiveYears(int year, int periodTypeId, int period)
        {
            IEnumerable<FinancePositionList> resultList;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Finance"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                query.Append("SELECT b.CompanyId,b.CompanyName,[Year]");
                query.Append(",CreationDate,AccruedExpenses,AdvancePaymentsToContractors");


                query.Append("FROM finance.FinanceList a INNER JOIN finance.Company b ");
                query.Append("ON a.CompanyId = b.CompanyId ");
                query.Append("INNER JOIN finance.ListPeriod c ");
                query.Append("ON c.FinanceListId = a.FinanceListId ");
                query.Append("WHERE Discriminator = " + "'" + "FinancePositionList" + "' ");
                query.Append("AND[Year] IN @years ");
                query.Append("AND c.PeriodTypeId = @PeriodTypeId AND c.Period = @Period ");
                query.Append("ORDER BY b.CompanyId, a.[Year] DESC ");

                resultList = conn.Query<FinancePositionList, Company,ListPeriod, FinancePositionList>(query.ToString(),
                   (a, b,c) =>
                   {
                       a.Company = b;
                       c.FinanceList = a;
                       return a;
                   },
                  new
                  {
                      years = new[] { year, year - 1 },
                      PeriodTypeId = periodTypeId,
                      Period = period
                  },
                    splitOn: "CompanyId,FinanceListId").AsEnumerable();
            }
            return resultList;
        }
```

---

[image]

---

**EDIT :**

I fix the problem now by changing the order of columns like this :
But I wonder if there are more enhancement to the code could i do ?

```
 public static IEnumerable<FinancePositionList> GetFinancialListsForConsecutiveYears(int year, int periodTypeId, int period)
        {
            IEnumerable<FinancePositionList> resultList;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ResolveConnectionString()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                query.Append("SELECT CreationDate,AccruedExpenses,AdvancePaymentsToContractors,[Year]");
                query.Append(",b.CompanyId,b.CompanyName,c.FinanceListId ");
                query.Append("FROM finance.FinanceList a INNER JOIN finance.Company b ");
                query.Append("ON a.CompanyId = b.CompanyId ");
                query.Append("INNER JOIN finance.ListPeriod c ");
                query.Append("ON c.FinanceListId = a.FinanceListId ");
                query.Append("WHERE Discriminator = " + "'" + "FinancePositionList" + "' ");
                query.Append("AND [Year] IN @years ");
                query.Append("AND c.PeriodTypeId = @PeriodTypeId AND c.Period = @Period ");
                query.Append("ORDER BY b.CompanyId, a.[Year] DESC ");

                resultList = conn.Query<FinancePositionList, Company, ListPeriod, FinancePositionList>(query.ToString(),
                   (a, b, c) =>
                   {
                       a.Company = b;
                       a.CompanyId = b.CompanyId;
                       a.FinanceListId = c.FinanceListId;
                       return a;
                   },
                  new
                  {
                      years = new[] { year, year - 1 },
                      PeriodTypeId = periodTypeId,
                      Period = period
                  },
                    splitOn: "CompanyId,FinanceListId").AsEnumerable();
            }
            return resultList;
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have mostly misunderstood the working of the `Multimapping` using `Dapper`, Your query yields the following columns:

```
**"CompanyId","CompanyName","Year","CreationDate","AccruedExpenses",
"AdvancePaymentsToContractors"**
```

Now the in the `multimapping` code, following is the dapper `Query` overload that you are calling (checked from the `source code`):

```
public static IEnumerable<TReturn> Query<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TReturn>(
this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TReturn> map, 
object param, IDbTransaction transaction, bool buffered, string splitOn, 
int? commandTimeout, CommandType? commandType)
```

Earlier I misunderstood the overall call, but now as it seems, issue is only with the Multi mapping type mapping using **SplitOn**, which you have already corrected, therefore the following would work, provided the correct `spliton` columns are available in the query result

```
conn.Query<FinancePositionList, Company,ListPeriod, FinancePositionList>(query.ToString(), (a, b,c) =>
                   {
                       a.Company = b;
                       c.FinanceList = a;
                       return a;
                   },
                  new
                 {
                    years = new[] { year, year - 1 },
                    PeriodTypeId = periodTypeId,
                    Period = period
                 }, splitOn: "CompanyId,FinanceListId")
```

Now only point remains to be clarified as I have posted in the comment is working of `years` parameter, which mostly an `integer array`, for the current query which is all text, this would work fine, but not for the `stored procedures`, where it would expect the same using `DataTable`, with same sequence and name of the columns as the collection can be supplied only using `Table Valued Parameters`. I don't foresee any more change required to the current use case.

**Edit to provide an example of Anonymous Parameters and Dynamic Parameters:**

**AnonymousParameters**

This simple anonymous type in C#, check [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/anonymous-types-in-C-Sharp/), idea is you can supply all the parameters using simple placeholder like `{max = <value>,min=<value>}` or even as is if the name match `{max,min}`, in both cases parameters are`@max` and `@min` , case doesn't matter, you are using the the  `AnonymousParameters` in your code for the parameters `years, PeriodTypeId, Period`, it will deduce the type and other details internally and would assume all to be input parameters

```
{years = new[] { year, year - 1 },PeriodTypeId = periodTypeId,Period = period}
```

**Dynamic Parameters**

They are more like Parameter class in Ado.Net, which gets you to add a parameter explicitly, following are the overloads in the Dapper code, you have to supply all the information like `Type, Direction` etc explicitly (code snippet from [dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) source code):

```
public partial class DynamicParameters : SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters, SqlMapper.IParameterLookup, SqlMapper.IParameterCallbacks
    {
    public void Add(string name, object value, DbType? dbType, ParameterDirection? direction, int? size)

    public void Add(string name, object value = null, DbType? dbType = null, ParameterDirection? direction = null, int? size = null, byte? precision = null, byte? scale = null)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,yeah this is the first time i use `Dapper` according to recommendations . I have a question here if i use the `first` one how to pass my parameters . all i want to do here is to execute a query has multiple joins allowing to pass parameters so i did that .

Comment: Parameters would be simple it can be done using Anonymous types or Dynamic Parameters, I prefer Anonymous type though they are restricted to the Input parameters, check examples @ https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net
or download the source code, that has good test cases to understand the usage

Comment: Could U rewrite my query to clarify the idea please

Comment: Currently you are getting the Compilation error, since no overload of query will accept it, it is searching for SplitOn and you are passing and anonymous type. Now I understood the  Anonymous type is the parameters, but you have supplied them incorrectly, let me rewrite

Comment: I wrote it already again with the following change 
`query.Append(",TradeAndPayables,TradeReceivables,TradingInvestments,[Year] ");
                query.Append(",b.CompanyId,b.CompanyName,c.FinanceListId ");`
Change the order of columns after i get the idea behind `split` and it works fine but i want any enhancement to the method

Comment: Please check the edited answer, I have pasted the actual Query API from Dapper code and tried to explain current version and possible modifications. Only Re-Write required in the original case was related to correct multi mapping to get the correct results.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm so confused , You had said that there are two ways to do the things : `Anonymous types` ,`Dynamic Parameters` ,and you had said that using both of them is totally wrong. but now you rewrite the same query ,Could you clarify the idea please ?

Comment: You have misunderstood my point somewhere, you have to use `Anonymous types` or `Dynamic Parameters`, there's no other option to pass the parameters, I cannot say, both are wrong :). Only point is `Anonymous types` can only be used for the Input parameters. I misinterpreted initially the overload used, which I verified down the line. As mentioned off late, you only have two concerns here, 1. correct usage of multi map (which you have corrected, post understanding the usage). 2. If the same  is shifted to Stored procedures, then `years` parameter need to be transformed into DataTable.

Comment: With `Dynamic Parameters`, you can pass all kinds of parameters, like Output, Return along with Input, if required, which is not possible for `Anonymous Type`, as they only used for Input parameters.

Comment: @I will be grateful if you provide an example one for anonymous type and one for dynamic

Comment: Apology for a late reply, check my edit to understand the difference, mail me directly for any more details, I hope it helps to clarify to an extent.

Comment: Just to add a link to another question that has some more extra help, in this case for multiple columns with the same name. [Dapper: Multi-Mapping with repeating column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996368/dapper-multi-mapping-with-repeating-column-names)
In my case, I needed a full solution, meaning I needed both 'question/answer'